# how to change the path in dotenv with various script commands (in package.json) such as : start , test , etc

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs, dotenv

well my problem is when I want to switch my script command in package.json like from "start" to "test" for running my Jest test which its commands like :

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon express/***",
  "serve": "node express/***",
  "dev": "node express/***",
  "test": "jest --watch"
},
```

and I call dotenv in my project like this

```
require("dotenv").config({
path: "express/config/.env",
});
```

The code above, help my to using my environment file like .env
but the problem is that when I want to test my project and I want to switch my script command (in package.json) from like "start" to "test" and change the main path of dotenv environment to something like test.env

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the environment type as an environment variable into your program like so. Note: you will need to use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) if you require multi-platform support.

Unix version:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon express/***",
  "serve": "NODE_ENV=production node express/***",
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev node express/***",
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch"
}
```

`cross-env` version:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon express/***",
  "serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node express/***",
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev node express/***",
  "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watch"
}
```

And then access them using the normal method of `process.env.NODE_ENV`

```
const envVariablePaths = {
  "production": "/path/here",
  "dev": "path/here",
  "test": "path/here",
}
require("dotenv").config({
  path: envVariablePaths[process.env.NODE_ENV],
})
```

More documentation can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js-html)